# PHPExcel reading file change blank cells to 0 in database

Tags: php, phpexcel, symfony-3.3

I am working on upload functionality of a website. The upload functionality takes an Excel or CSV file and upload it to MySQL database. I have a problem with blank cells. Since I am using PHPExcel library, it changes the blank cells to 0 in database. I want to handle the blank cell values in database and store null instead of 0.

```
$excelObj = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($path_file);
$sheet = $excelObj->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

Comment: So how are you writing to the database?... especially with those entries in the array returned by PHPExcel that are null values?

Comment: @MarkBaker I am writing via doctrine, via a loop on array elements.

foreach($sheet as $i=>$row) {
                   $user = new TempAdminData();
                   $user->setDistrictCode(trim($row['A']));
                   $user->setSubDistName(trim($row['B']));

                   $em->persist($user);
                   $em->flush();

Comment: Well a `trim()` will cast any nulls to strings

Comment: @MarkBaker but when you remove the trim() it stores 0 for blank cells as before.

Comment: Then your problem lies somewhere in doctrine..... because you should be getting a null back from PHPExcel for null cells (and you should be able to verify this).... note though, that Excel also allows cells with empty strings

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you. I resolved the issue finally. check every cell before pushing to db.